# having issues with ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm new to ruby and not sure why my code won't work when I rake it in the command prompt. I get something that seems to say syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input and I'm not sure how to exactly fix it. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
def temperature_conversion_functions
    def ftoc(x)
        "Converts freezing temperature"
        ftoc(32) == 0
        end

        "Converts boiling temperature"
        ftoc(212) == 100
        end

        "Converts body temperature"
        ftoc(98.6) == 37
        end

        "converts arbitrary temperature"
        ftoc(68) == 20
        end
    end

    def ctof(x)

        "converts freezing temperature"
        ctof(0) == 32
        end

        "converts boiling temperature"
        ctof(100) == 212
        end

        "converts arbitrary temperature"
        ctof(20) == 68
        end

        "converts body temperature"
        ctof(37) == 98.6
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: By "get something that seems to say," do you mean "am seeing an error that reads"? It's typically best to post your error messages verbatim.

Comment: Also....what are you trying to do here? It looks like you're trying to write a namespace (i.e. a module or a class) containing these two functions, then document them (since you're showing example usage), but instead of documentation you're writing actual code (specifically you're writing boolean expressions that call the function you're supposedly defining). Can you explain your thinking?

Comment: Also also, it's unclear what you mean by "when I rake it in the command prompt." Rake is a "make-like" build system for Ruby, not a Ruby execution environment.

Comment: Are these intended to be unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've many `end` keywords where they aren't necessary. Code can be enclosed in blocks like so:

```
x = 5
if x > 3
  puts "x is greater than 3!"
end
```

Similar to the `if` and `end` enclosure, there are other keywords like `do`, `def`, `class`, `while`, etc, all with different usages.

Other stuff:

1. You appear to be commenting your code using string, like `"Converts freezing temperature"`. It just so happens that ruby will evaluate the string and then do nothing with it. However, the proper way to write comments is with a `#` symbol:

   ```
   # This is a comment. The line below is executed code
   puts "Printing out this string"
   ```
2. You're recursing `ftoc` and `ctof`. Careful about causing infinite loops! Here's an example expansion of the recursion:

   ```
   def ftoc(x)     # define the `ftoc(x)` method
     ftoc(32) == 9 # let's expand this line
   end
   ```

   the `ftoc(32)` "expands" to `ftoc(32) == 9`, because that's how `ftoc(x)` is defined:

   ```
   def ftoc(x)
     ( ftoc(32) == 9 ) == 9 # "expanded" once
   end
   ```

   and again:

   ```
   def ftoc(x)
     ( ( ftoc(32) == 9 ) == 9 ) == 9 # "expanded" twice
   end
   ```

   and will continue forever, endlessly
3. There's no need to define the two `ftoc` and `ctof` methods inside the `temperature_conversion_functions` method. If you'd like to organize several related methods together, I would suggest using a `module`:

   ```
   module TemperatureConversion
     def TemperatureConversion.ftoc(f) # This is an example. More idiomatic way is shown below
       return (f - 32) * 5.0/9
     end

     def self.ctof(c) # the 'self' in this line means/is-the-same-as 'TemperatureConversion'
       return c * 9.0/5 + 32
     end
   end

   # now you can use the module and its methods
   # convert freezing
   puts TemperatureConversion.ftoc(32) # will output 0.0
   ```

Comment: Sure thing!
If you found my post helpful, would you mind accepting it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Align the `end` keywords correctly - under the corresponding `def`, `class`, `if`, etc. keyword - and the problem will be clear. (There are actually several problems that are made fairly apparent by correct indenting.)

```
def ftoc(x)
    "Converts freezing temperature"
    # What this is "recusion and check" supposed to be anyway?
    # It's recursive because it's inside the same (ftoc) method.
    ftoc(32) == 0
end

    "Converts boiling temperature"
    ftoc(212) == 100
    # Uhh, where does this `end` go? It's "unexpected".
    end
```

In any case, consider that the conversion function should merely be [a simple equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit)

```
def ftoc(f)
    return (f - 32) * 5.0/9
end
```

And then it can be used as so

```
puts "42f is #{ftoc(42)}c"
```